# Which blockchains have an asset / token exchange built in directly into the core wallet software?

Tags: ardor, decentralized-exchanges

Doing some research on fully decentralized exchanges. Which blockchains *core* wallets have a built in asset / token exchange? iDex and etherdelta are built by 3rd party developers, so that doesn't really count as one would have to trust the 3rd party implementations.

I know nxt and ardor have an asset exchange built in directly to their wallet, but are there other blockchains that have something similar?

Comment: I think this is a very strange question. You're asking about decentralized exchanges, but require that it's somehow created by a very centralized team responsible for the currency/blockchain too? You can use any wallet software.

Comment: Umm.. not sure how its a strange questions and not sure what you mean by its centralized. I'm just curious to what other wallets have a built in asset/token exchange into its core wallet that *isnt* built by a 3rd party but by the core developers of the blockchain itself. I know bitshares has one built in, but wanted to see what others there were.

Comment: The mere fact that you talk about "the core developers of the blockchain" sounds like you don't really care about decentralization. Generally these ecosystems are collaborative efforts, and you should hope that one team doesn't have a privileged position.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. Yes, I agree it is quite centralized if you rely on just a "core" set of devs that build blockchain software and its dex. Well, I'd still like to know if there is a "truely" decentralized type o exchange, aside from the ones I've found so far. Currently its such a niche category and small group of people that have done it, its tricky to sometimes shift through all the bs that is out there. thanks.